# jquery - each loop with condition giving wrong result

Tags: jquery

I am looping through a object, and conditionally i am consoling the result. but i am getting all the 3 result, instead to get just 2. what is wrong with my code?

Any suggestion please?

my code :

```
 var processModules = function (mData) {
    var lcalmData = obj = {'content':'new content','navigation':'newNavigation','form':'newform'}; var title;
    $('body').append(
        $.each(lcalmData, function (i,val) {
            title = (i === 'content' || i === 'navigation')  ? $('<div />') : i === 'form' ? $('<form />') : null;
            return title;
        } )  
    )
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WsQ6K/3/)

Comment: coudl you provide a example of what mData looks like?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by doing this? Looks like there could be a better solution.

Comment: according to the data, i would make the element and append to body

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is problematic:

`val === 'content' || 'navigation'`

I suppose you meant to check whether `val` is equal to one of these values? ) But it doesn't work this way: as `===` operator priority is higher than `||` one, it's essentially the same as...

`(val === 'content') || 'navigation'`

... in other words, always a truthy value.

What you intended may be rewritten just as simple as...

`... (i === 'content' || i === 'navigation')`

... as it's the index (key) that should be checked, not value.

Comment: on printing i am getting only the null values.. can you look the jsfiddle

Comment: @3gwebtrain Updated my answer, check the [fixed fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WsQ6K/1/)

Comment: all i did that for appending element to body, now from the each function i try to append the element, something is going wrong again, can you check my fiddle again? thanks in advance.

Comment: @3gwebtrain Well, there's another problem: if you need to create some array of elements based on another collection, use `$.map` instead of `$.each`. Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WsQ6K/4/) for example of how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/WsQ6K/2/

You were using val instead of i i.e the attribute name not the value

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this:

```
var title = ( val === 'content' || val === 'navigation' ) ? val.type  : null;
```

Brackets () are probably not required. You are now testing whether val === 'content' OR whether 'navigation' is 'true'. And the latter, in fact, is always true.